# Good computer, good windows performance, terrible Ubuntu performance?

Tags: performance

I'm quite the noob to Ubuntu and I tried it a long time ago and had this problem, and after reinstalling today i'm still having it. I duel boot alongside Windows 10 which runs perfect, but on Ubuntu it's absolute trash. I can't watch a youtube video without freezing and lagging, and even the menu for lubuntu lags. Yes, obviously I updated my Nvidia drivers in the additional drivers so please do not suggest that. Can anyone possibly give me some help? Thank you!

Specs:

Ubuntu 16.04

Memory: 24 GB

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CP

Graphics: NVidia GeForce GTX 745

OS Type: 64-bit

Comment: Is there a probe that can be ran ? ... Anyone ?

Comment: In a terminal issue ... dmesg  ... look for clues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030466/ubuntu-18-04-keeps-freezing-nvidia)

Comment: This question was written before the question it is said to duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA has always been problematic. I understand that, you have already updated the drivers, but here is another process of doing it:

1. Open Terminal and type `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings`
2. Go to Additional Drivers as you did before
3. Choose the latest driver (Open Source) and restart
4. It worked on 14.04, hope it works