# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 18.04

My PC with Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing randomly. I know, it's very often topic. I've tried multiple nvidia-xxx versions, with no luck.

**ubuntu-drivers devices**

- == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
- modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000611sv00001458sd00003468bc03sc00i00
- vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
- model    : G92 [GeForce 8800 GT]
- driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
- driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
- driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

Last time it worked with Ubuntu 16.04 + nvidia-304_304.135. After upgrade do to 17.10 it was freezing too. Upgrade to 18.04 did not helped either.

**nvidia-304_304.135 - old**

- does not boot to login screen
- it's in black screen loop (some booting text is shown, but refreshed every 3 seconds)

**nvidia-304.137 - third-party free**

- it's the same as 304.135

**nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended (ubuntu-drivers autoinstall)**

- freezing (even 2 times, when I wrote this question)
- rendering works nice and smooth

**xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin**

- does not freeze
- it has terrible slow rendering

**nvidia-390 (from ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa)**

- does not seems to work, because it's slow as nouveau

I don't need nvidia driver, I can live with nouveau (with repaired rendering). Any tips to how to get further? (repair nouveau rendering or get non-freezing driver working?)

Comment: Have you purged nouveau when you install the nvidia drivers?

Comment: I've added /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf with content "blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0". It should be the same, but I will try to purge it too.

Comment: Tried that and it's the same - slow rendering. And the software center sais something like "Custom manual driver installed".

Comment: I have the same issue except my workstation will freeze and become unresponsive. I cannot even ALT-F3 to a terminal window. However, I can go to another PC and ssh into my workstation. But a reboot is all that will fix it.

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with radomly freezes on Ubuntu 18.04 but with `Geforce 9600M GT` graphics but only with proprietary driver 340. Problem was in Adaptive Mode. This graphics have three or four clock levels. When I set up only full performance mode on boot I had never more any freeze.

Try adding this to autorun:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having laggy video performance in VLC and Chrome. I was running Nvidia 390.30 drivers. I tried other suggestions on other threads, but ultimately updating to Nvidia 390.48 drivers fixed my laggy video.

In Ubuntu 18.04 using this command with install the Nvidia 390.48 drivers:

`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Either uninstall all others, or use the Software & Update app to switch.

Comment: I've tried that earlier - it does not help.

Comment: Maybe also [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/729644/349837) could help? `sudo apt install nvidia-prime && sudo prime-select intel`

Answer (score 0):

I have a very strange solution which worked for me. Download nvidia driver as .run file from nvidia website. Run it as root, it will propose you to disable nouveau by wrting some file to modprobe. Accept it and reboot. Then use apt-get to install something like nvidia-driver-410 (or what have you).