# How can I fix random freezing on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, freeze

How can I fix random OS freezing on Ubuntu 18.04? It is not only a graphics problem because I cannot use any of the virtual terminals on Ubuntu and the keyboard does not respond. I switched to Intel graphics and back to Nvidia graphics card, but nothing changed. I have an SSD. Every time after a write operation (for example saving on Gedit) the cursor becomes an hourglass. Can it be related to the freezing problem?

These are important logs:

```
- 10:18:28 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill
   (0x12) 
- 10:18:28 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel
   /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0 
- 10:18:27 pulseaudio:
   [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio
   agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
   org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
- 10:18:19 bluetoothd:
   Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12) 
- 10:18:19
   spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel
   /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0 
- 10:18:18 wpa_supplicant: dbus:
   Failed to construct signal 
- 10:18:17 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode:
   Blocked through rfkill (0x12) 
- 10:18:17 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not
   signed with a trusted key 
- 10:18:15 kernel: Couldn't get size:
   0x800000000000000e 
- 10:18:15 kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db
   list 10:18:15 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e 
- 10:14:37
   gdm3: GLib: g_hash_table_find: assertion 'version ==
   hash_table->version' failed 
- 08:58:11 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode:
   Blocked through rfkill (0x12) 
- 08:58:10 spice-vdagent: Cannot access
   vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
- 08:58:10
   pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a
   handsfree audio agent with ofono:
   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not
   provided by any .service files 
- 08:57:58 bluetoothd: Failed to set
   mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12) 
- 08:57:58 spice-vdagent: Cannot
   access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
- 08:57:56 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
-   08:57:56 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal 
- 08:57:55
   kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
- 08:57:55
   nvidia-persiste: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that
   the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 121 has
   read and write permissions for those files.
- 08:57:55 kernel: PKCS#7
   signature not signed with a trusted key 
-  08:57:55 bluetoothd: Failed
   to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12) 
- 08:57:55 kernel: PKCS#7
   signature not signed with a trusted key 
- 08:57:53 kernel: Couldn't get
   size: 0x800000000000000e 
- 08:57:53 kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI
   db list 
- 08:57:53 kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
```

Comment: You need provide OS specific logs or question will be marked as duplicated.

Comment: Hi had this same problem, until I updated to the latest kernel version 4.19 (I used [these](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-kernel-ubuntu-1804/) instructions) then it disappeared. Hope this helps. 
I couldn't find what was causing it though, most likely a hardware problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030466/ubuntu-18-04-keeps-freezing-nvidia)