# Ubuntu constant freezing

Tags: 18.04, freeze

hello i decided to switch to Ubuntu and start learning Linux. Did a full install of Ubuntu, updated it , added nvidia drives and everything was working fine. Next day when i start the laptop i keeps freezing, is freezing randomly but constantly. I try to reinstall and update , it was working fine then  shut down the laptop and start it again the next day and the same problem starts again random constant freezes . I'm suing lenovo legion y530 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030466/ubuntu-18-04-keeps-freezing-nvidia)

Answer (score 0):

i did a new fresh minimal install it the problem got resolved