# How to solve system freezing or crashing due to NVIDIA on Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04?

Tags: nvidia, freeze, crash

I have a DELL G3 3590, with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650, and I experienced system crash or freeze on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. How to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030466/ubuntu-18-04-keeps-freezing-nvidia)

Comment: @kenorb , you are right, questions are similar. My answer just adds something else to the most voted answer from your suggested question.

Comment: If it adds something else to the most voted answer, please copy/paste your answer here and post it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found for preventing system freezing for DELL G3 3590, with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 (it may apply to other NVIDEA computers), on both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 is:

Add to `.profile`:

```
nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1
```

Open `/etc/default/grub` and edit the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

by adding `"acpi_rev_override=1"` to the list, so it becomes

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```